# Link to root using base_url element

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm setting the `base_url` element in my application. To link to the root, I can use an empty `href` attribute on an anchor tag.

```
<a href=" ">Home</a>
```

However, when generating links from a database that requires a path attribute, I can't put in an empty string. Is there some other way I can link to the root of my application?

Currently it's in a subdirectory, but the name of that subdirectory might change or it may be hosted on a subdomain in the future. So the `base_url` element could change.

Comment: If you're using a database, I'm assuming you're also using c# or php?
In this case, my personal recommendation would be to create a "config.php" file or something and set a global variable `BASE_URL`. This has been my solution as a html base url gives nothing but trouble in my humble opinion. This was quite insightful to me:http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399 - also, using `/` should work. You could later write a small script that checks if the database urls and `base_url` match up, and search and replace if they don't.

Comment: @Babydead - The JavaScript framework I'm using, AngularJS, requires a base_url to be set. I was hoping I could work with it rather than set up overrides on the server side to work around it. But yes, it does seem to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Hmm... What I take heavy issue with, is that it messes up your css and js paths when you change the base tag on other pages, but if you put it on the base domain, it's going to link all url's like `#` or `#element` back to the base url page, so you'd have to work it all in dynamically anyway. If you're going to work with a base tag, the only thing I could recommend is to always use absolute links (`http://www.yourdomain.com/page`)